# Numbered lists using <h2> and <h3> tags impact on SEO

Tags: seo, css

I have several blog posts with list or a series of steps.  I.e.,

#### 1.  First Item/Step

blah, blah, blah

#### 2.  Second Item/Step

blah, blah, blah

#### 3.  Third Item/Step

blah, blah, blah

These steps are usually formatted with either `<h2>` or `<h3>`tags.  I've tried formatting as `<ol><li><h2>First item</h2></li></ol>` to do numbered lists, but the number style is different from the `<h2>` style and the two styles appear exclusive of each other.

I.e, the display is:

1. **First item** (note the # isn't the same as the text)

blah, blah, blah

So, I've just manually included the numeric value inside of the `<h3>` tag like `<h3>2.  Second step</h3>`.

I'm guessing it would be possible for search engines to recognize numbered `<h3>` tags as lists even without the `<ol><li>First item</li></ol>` tag but I'm curious if there's a better way to do this from an SEO perspective?  Should I be using `<itemlist>` schema or some other formatting option?  Or is this just a matter of changing my CSS file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Schemas are good for SEO so where you can use them it is a good idea. As for what schema to use, I would use [Steps](https://schema.org/steps)

As for the rest if the markup, do they **need** to be in `<h2></h2>` or `<h3></h3>` headers?

Why not use CSS? For example

### html

```
<span class='h3-font-size'>1. First Item/Step</span>

blah, blah, blah

<span class='h3-font-size'>2. Second Item/Step</span>
```

### CSS

```
.h3-font-size{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: It's not a formatting issue as much as an SEO issue.  `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags tell Google how your content is organized.  However, numbered lists are good for telling Google you have a list.  I'll take a look at the `step` schema.

Answer (score 1):

Heading elements are for identifying headings and not for identifying placement within a list. If a list item has a heading, it can have a `<h1>` for each list item which will then identify it properly as the head of a sectioned content. So:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or all `<h2>` or `<h3>`, etc.

**Never** use heading elements for formatting or styling!